# How to compute IOU(overlaps) using 2 pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

In object detection, IOU(intersection over union) is a value between 0 and 1 that represents the percentage of overlap between 2 boxes drawn on an object in a certain image.

To help you understand what that is, here's an illustration:

[image: iou]

The red frame is the real value with coordinates x1(top left), y1(bottom left), x2(top right), y2(bottom right).

The purple frame is the predicted value with coordinates x1_predicted, y1_predicted, x2_predicted, y2_predicted.

The yellow shaded square is the iou, if it's value is greater than a certain threshold(0.5 by convention) the prediction evaluates as True, otherwise it's a False.

Here's the code that calculates IOU for 2 boxes:

```
def get_iou(box_true, box_predicted):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = box_true
    x1p, y1p, x2p, y2p = box_predicted
    if not all([x2 > x1, y2 > y1, x2p > x1p, y2p > y1p]):
        return 0
    far_x = np.min([x2, x2p])
    near_x = np.max([x1, x1p])
    far_y = np.min([y2, y2p])
    near_y = np.max([y1, y1p])
    inter_area = (far_x - near_x + 1) * (far_y - near_y + 1)
    true_box_area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
    pred_box_area = (x2p - x1p + 1) * (y2p - y1p + 1)
    iou = inter_area / (true_box_area + pred_box_area - inter_area)
    return iou
```

I have the predictions and the actual data contained in 2 csv files which I read into 2 pandas DataFrame objects and go from there.

For every image, I extract detections of a certain object type (ex: car) and the actual data, here's an example for 1 object(car) in 1 image(Beverly_hills1.png)

```
Actual:
              Image Path Object Name  X_min  Y_min  X_max  Y_max
3842  Beverly_hills1.png         Car    760    432    911    550
3843  Beverly_hills1.png         Car    612    427    732    526
3844  Beverly_hills1.png         Car    462    412    597    526
3845  Beverly_hills1.png         Car    371    432    544    568

Detections:
                  image object_name   x1   y1   x2   y2
594  Beverly_hills1.png         Car  612  422  737  539
595  Beverly_hills1.png         Car  383  414  560  583
```

Here's how I would compare:

```
def calculate_overlaps(self, detections, actual):
    calculations = []
    detection_groups = detections.groupby('image')
    actual_groups = actual.groupby('Image Path')
    for item1, item2 in zip(actual_groups, detection_groups):
        for detected_index, detected_row in item2[1].iterrows():
            detected_coordinates = detected_row.values[2: 6]
            detected_overlaps = []
            coords = []
            for actual_index, actual_row in item1[1].iterrows():
                actual_coordinates = actual_row.values[4: 8]
                detected_overlaps.append((
                    self.get_iou(actual_coordinates, detected_coordinates)))
                coords.append(actual_coordinates)
            detected_row['max_iou'] = max(detected_overlaps)
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = coords[int(np.argmax(detected_overlaps))]
            for match, value in zip([f'{item}_match'
                                     for item in ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2']],
                                    [x1, y1, x2, y2]):
                detected_row[match] = value
            calculations.append(detected_row)
    return pd.DataFrame(calculations)
```

For every object type this will run which is inefficient.

The end result will look like this:

```
                     image object_name    x1  ...  y1_match  x2_match  y2_match
594     Beverly_hills1.png         Car   612  ...       427       732       526
595     Beverly_hills1.png         Car   383  ...       432       544       568
1901   Beverly_hills10.png         Car   785  ...       432       940       578
2015  Beverly_hills101.png         Car   832  ...       483      1240       579
2708  Beverly_hills103.png         Car   376  ...       466      1333       741
...                    ...         ...   ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
618    Beverly_hills93.png         Car   922  ...       406       851       659
625    Beverly_hills93.png         Car  1002  ...       406       851       659
1081   Beverly_hills94.png         Car   398  ...       426       527       559
1745   Beverly_hills95.png         Car  1159  ...       438       470       454
1746   Beverly_hills95.png         Car   765  ...       441       772       474

[584 rows x 14 columns]
```

How to simplify / vectorize this and eliminate for loops? can this be done using `np.where()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I noticed your `get_iou` function has a condition: `x2 > x1, y2 > y1, x2p > x1p, y2p > y1p`. You should make sure that condition holds for both data frames.

Second, the `actual` has columns `Image Path` and `Object Name`, while `detections` has `image` and `object_name`. You may want to change the corresponding columns to one single name.

That said, here's my solution with `merge`:

```
def area(df,columns):
    '''
    compute the box area 
    @param df: a dataframe
    @param columns: box coordinates (x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max)
    '''
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = [df[col] for col in columns]
    return (x2-x1)*(y2-y1)

# rename the columns
actual = actual.rename(columns={'Image Path':'image', 'Object Name':'object_name'})

# merge on `image` and `object_name`
total_df = (actual.merge(detections, on=['image', 'object_name'])

# compute the intersection
total_df['x_max_common'] = total_df[['X_max','x2']].min(1)
total_df['x_min_common'] = total_df[['X_min','x1']].max(1)
total_df['y_max_common'] = total_df[['Y_max','y2']].min(1)
total_df['y_min_common'] = total_df[['Y_min','y1']].max(1)

# valid intersection
true_intersect = (total_df['x_max_common'] > total_df['x_min_common']) & \
                 (total_df['y_max_common'] > total_df['y_min_common'])

# filter total_df with valid intersection
total_df = total_df[true_intersect]

# the various areas
actual_areas = area(total_df, ['X_min','Y_min','X_max','Y_max'])
predicted_areas = area(total_df, ['x1','y1','x2','y2'])
intersect_areas = area(total_df,['x_min_common','y_min_common','x_max_common', 'y_max_common'])

# IOU
iou_areas = intersect_areas/(actual_areas + predicted_areas - intersect_areas)

# assign the IOU to total_df
total_df['IOU'] = iou_areas
```

Comment: wow, that's really brilliant, thanks, total execution time on 16 object classes is 2% of the total execution time with 3 nested for loops [~18 seconds - 0.335 seconds] ! I really like this

Comment: There is something that I don't understand though, how to unmerge after calculating the ious? I want to calculate true positives, false positives next, so I need the initial predictions separately and after the calculations the length of `total_df` is > than initial predictions

Comment: @sK500 True positive can be done, for example `total_df['IOU'].gt(threshold).groupby([total_df['image'], total_df['object_name']]).any()`. However, false positive (incorrect classification) is somewhat harder since we only merge the correct `object_name`.

Comment: I'm using this to calculate the mAP(mean average precision) for each class and the detector mAP, so any workarounds? and btw, I run this on every class data(detection/actual) separately if this makes any difference

Comment: Actually, `false_positive = total - true_positive`, so yes, you can do that.

Comment: and there are multiple images with the same name but different object, because the image of course can contain more than one object per class(ex: cars, people ...) would this produce side effects? as i noticed the number of car true positives after thresholding with 0.5, is greater than the number of actual detections by like 15 cars, the rest of classes are behaving as expected: true positives < total detections

Comment: That should be possible as well, but to be honest, it deserves a question on it's own, since this goes beyond a comment.